# Pandas frame.append method is deprecated

Tags: pandas, append, concatenation, future, deprecated

Code:

```
for ticker in tickers:
var = yf.Ticker(ticker).info
frame = pd.DataFrame([var])
df = df.append(frame)
```

Error:FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
df = df.append(frame)

Thanks.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: What is unclear about "Use pandas.concat instead"?

Comment: explains why it was deprecated , I hope this helps
[https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/35407]

Comment: Not sure what the correct syntax will be.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.